# Reading from and writing to a file without passing around filename

Tags: file, io, go

I was looking for a way to write to and then read from a file in different parts of my code, without passing the filename around and without consumers needing to know it was coming from a file.

I came up with this `FilePipe` based on `io.Pipe`:

```
package pipe

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func FilePipe(name string) (*io.PipeReader, *io.PipeWriter) {
    inr, inw := io.Pipe()
    outr, outw := io.Pipe()

    go func() {
        // Open the file for writing
        f, err := os.Create(name)
        if err != nil {
            outw.CloseWithError(err)
            return
        }

        // Copy the input to the file
        _, err = io.Copy(f, inr)
        f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            outw.CloseWithError(err)
            return
        }

        // Open the file for reading
        f, err = os.Open(name)
        if err != nil {
            outw.CloseWithError(err)
            return
        }

        // Copy the file to the output
        _, err = io.Copy(outw, f)
        f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            outw.CloseWithError(err)
            return
        }
        outw.Close()
    }()

    return outr, inw
}
```

What do you think? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the file an important side-effect? If so you could do an io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(thefile, otheroutput), input).

Comment: Yeah, in this case it is an important side-effect. We don't want to start processing the results until we've finished writing everything to the file successfully.

Comment: Please provide a full example with a caller of FilePipe and explain what exactly your code should do and how you want to avoid races. I see no mutex or channel, so I can't see how this could work nor how you want it to work.

Comment: You should always check the error return by `os.File.Close` if the file was written to. An error writing a file may not get reported until the file gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a teereader:

```
inr, inw := io.Pipe()
f, _ := os.Create(name)
tr := io.TeeReader(inr, f)
return tr, inw
```

use this code in go routine and handle errors

Comment: For a go noob like me: how does this work, why is it better than the solution in the question?